# How use User Delegation SAS Or Azure RBAC to grant permissions on storage account containers for azure active directory B2C users?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c, azure-rbac, sas-token

I ‘m working with Active Directory B2C and Storage account in Azure.
I would like to use User Delegation SAS or Azure RBAC to grant limited access to containers and blobs.

I linked my new Tenant to my subscription, but I cannot create storage account in this directory or any other azure resource.

I created storage account in the default folder, but I cannot use User Delegation SAS or Azure RBAC to manage access to storage account because users are in the Active Directory B2C Tenant.

I need some help to achieve this requirement
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that, they key is to add the user as a guest user to your current aad.

[image]

[image]

Then Invite the user to your current aad.