# How use User Delegation SAS Or Azure RBAC to grant permissions on storage account containers for azure active directory B2C users (Custom Domain)?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c, azure-rbac, sas-token

I have created a login module using Azure AD B2C. B2C tenant have a custom login page as well as a custom domain.

I have also created an Azure Blob Storage Container for hosting HTML files of my website.

I have a requirement that only the logged-in user access HTML files, and no one else should be allowed to access the files.

Can anyone please help me understand how I can provide access to html files to the logged-in users?

[I know that a similar question has already been answered on StackOverflow. In the answer, it was mentioned to create external users on Azure Active Directory and provide access to users through Active Directory. The only issue with this method is that the custom domain can't be used for the login page of Active Directory. I wanted to add this question to the comment of the existing query, but because of low reputation, I'm not able to add a comment to that question]

Answer (score 1):

•   You can assign the ‘Reader’ role for all the users who are logging in with the Azure AD credentials to read and access the contents of the blob storage. Also, if you have enabled access to the blob storage account keys via the shared key authorization, shared key access must be permitted for the storage account during its provisioning.

•   Also, you can assign the ‘Reader and Data Access’ role to all the users who will be accessing the login page and accessing the blob storage contents as they will be able to view storage account resources, but not modify them. It does not provide read permissions to data in Azure Storage, but only to account management resources. The Reader role is necessary so that users can navigate to blob containers in the Azure portal.

•   Thus, if you want users with increasing levels of access to the blob storage, you can assign the ‘Storage account contributor’, ‘ARM Contributor role’ and ‘ARM Owner role’ in increasing order respectively. Also, if you want external users to access the blob storage content for a limited time duration or continuous monitored manner, you can share the SAS URI or access keys accordingly. Also, once you assign the roles according to requirement, you can generate SAS URI access tokens also for additional security.

Please refer the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/shared-key-authorization-prevent?tabs=portal

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal

Comment: In the answer, you have mentioned the process for Azure Active Directory. But, with Azure Active Directory, I can't use custom pages with a custom domain for login, MFA, or password reset. So, I need to use Azure Active Directory B2C. Can you please explain how I can create user delegation sas using active directory b2c, as I can't create a storage account on the b2c tenant?

Comment: You can create a user delegation SAS token using Azure Active Directory by adding the concerned user whom you want to delegate the access permissions by adding that user as a guest user in the default or tenant Azure Active Directory and then creating a SAS token for that user. Please follow the below link for more information: - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719670/how-use-user-delegation-sas-or-azure-rbac-to-grant-permissions-on-storage-accoun

Comment: How will I use a custom login page and a custom domain name for the login mechanism?

Comment: When you create an Azure AD B2C tenant, you provide the domain name that you want to associate with that tenant, thus that will become your customized domain name and the login page will be accordingly only. Also, in a subscription, you can create multiple tenants with different domains.

Comment: Yes, For custom domain and login pages we are using